# Find $\text{card}(T_n( \mathbb R ) \cap O(n))$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

Let $T_n( \mathbb R )$ be the set of upper triangular matrices of size $n$.

Let $O(n)$ be the set of general orthogonal matrices and $SO(n)$ the set of special orthogonal matrices.

Find the cardinal of $T_n( \mathbb R ) \cap O(n)$ and $T_n( \mathbb R ) \cap SO(n)$.

For the second question, I found that case $n = 2$ is pretty easy, since 
$\forall M \in SO(2), M$ can be written as  $M = \begin{bmatrix} 
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) 
\end{bmatrix}$, $\theta \in \mathbb R$.

We can see that $M$ is upper triangular *iff* $\theta = k \pi$ with $k \in \mathbb Z$.

So that gives us $\text{card}(T_2( \mathbb R ) \cap SO(2)) = 2$.

I have trouble generalizing this result.

Comment: Can you prove that the inverse of an upper triangular matrix is an upper triangular matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $M\in T_n(\mathbb{R})\cap O(n)$. Then $M^{-1}=M^T$ (since $M\in O(n)$) and $M^{-1}\in T_n(\mathbb{R})$ (since the inverse of an upper triangular matrix is also upper triangular. So, $M$ and $M^T$ are both upper triangular, which means that $M$ is, in fact, a diagonal matrix. Now, how many diagonal matrices are there in $O(n)$? And in $SO(n)$?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Let $M = (m_{ij}). $Since $\det(M) = 1$ and $\forall (i,j) \in [\![ 1, n]\!]^2, m_{ij} \in [-1, 1]$, the only choices for the coefficients of $M$ is ${-1,1}$. So, $\text{card}(T_n( \mathbb R ) \cap O(n)) = \text{card}(T_n( \mathbb R ) \cap SO(n)) = 2^n$.
Is that all right?

Comment: No. I don't know how you jump from $M_{ij}\in[-1,1]$ to $M_{ij}\in\{1,-1\}$. Besides, $\operatorname{card}(T_n(\mathbb{R})\cap SO(n))=2^{n-1}$.

Comment: We know that $M \in O(n)$ so every column of $M$ has norm $1$.
But why is $\text{card}(T_n( \mathbb R ) \cap SO(n)) = 2^{n-1}$?

Comment: Because, the number of $-1$'s in the main diagonal of a diagonal matrix in $SO(n)$ must be even, so that its determinant is $-1$.

Comment: Is that really? Because $\begin{bmatrix} 
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) 
\end{bmatrix} \in SO(2)$ and has determinant $1$.

Comment: It is not triangular, right?!

Comment: Oh. My bad. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Actually I'm still thinking that $I_2 \in SO (2) $ and has determinant $1$ .

Comment: Indeed. It it has an even number of $-1$'s, right?! Actually, it has exactly **zero** $-1$'s.

Comment: So there was a mistake in one of your comment, determinant should be $+1$.

Comment: You are right, but I cannot edit anymore.